# Loading an animation in Unity 2D at runtime

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am making a game where I randomly spawn different characters, some of which I have made animations for (so their movement won't be too static). But I can't seem to figure out how to use the animation on the prefab. I've tried to add the animation to the Prefab and I have checked off 'Play Automatically' and set 'Culling Type' as 'Always Animate'. However it's still the first prefab only that loads. I would prefer to control the animation at runtime (UnityScript) if possible, but I can't seem to figure out how.

Dunno if this helps in any way, but the character I am currently trying to get to animate has a set routine of actions it does before it gets destroyed, so it will move the same specific route every time.

Answer (score 0):

Set the rig/animation type to "Legacy" in the model import options (under the tab/button "rig").

Then you should be able to see the animations in the model's properties and when you use that model in a prefab.

Then in a script on that prefab/gameobject you should be able to do animations["nameofanimation"].Play() and that should do the trick.